# How to profile how many instructions are executed during a cuda kernel launch

Tags: cuda, gpu, profiling, nvidia

I want to know how many fp32 and int32 instructions are executed in a cuda kernel during a launch. Is there any way to profile it via Nvidia Nsight Compute?

Comment: yes, there is.  It's important to know which profiler you intend to use and which GPU you are profiling on.

Comment: Nsight Compute for Nvidia GPU

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to profile it via Nvidia Nsight Compute?

For nsight compute, the [relevant metrics](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/NsightComputeCli/index.html#nvprof-metric-comparison) are as follows:

```
fp32 instructions executed:    smsp__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_fp32_pred_on.sum
integer instructions executed: smsp__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_integer_pred_on.sum
```

Example:

```
$ ncu --metrics smsp__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_fp32_pred_on.sum ./t2003
...
==PROF== Disconnected from process 27520
[27520] t2003@127.0.0.1
  kernel_1(const float *, float *), 2022-Apr-23 23:24:34, Context 1, Stream 16
    Section: Command line profiler metrics
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------
    smsp__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_fp32_pred_on.sum                               inst                         10,240
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------

  kernel_2(const float *, float *), 2022-Apr-23 23:24:34, Context 1, Stream 17
    Section: Command line profiler metrics
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------
    smsp__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_fp32_pred_on.sum                               inst                         10,240
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------

$
```

Note that recent versions of Nsight Compute are [intended to be used](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ReleaseNotes/index.html#gpu-support) on Volta  and newer (compute capability 7.0 and higher) GPUs only.